# operator >> in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the “>>” operator in C# do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485528/what-does-the-operator-in-c-sharp-do)

> Also related: [Doubling a number - shift left vs. multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3059719/385844)

This is code in C#.

I just need to know if I'm right.

I'm not sure with using operator `>>`.

this code:

```
winHalfWidth = this.ClientSize.Width >> 1; // both is int
```

make the same as:

```
winHalfWidth = this.ClientSize.Width / 2;
```

and if I'm right so, this code should do:

```
quaterWidht = this.ClientSize.Width >> 2;
```

should do same as:

```
quaterWidth = this.ClientSize.Width / 4;
```

So 2 questions:

1. Is it right?
2. Is any difference between using `>>` and `/`?

   - When we speak about int values?
   - When we speak abou float values? (I thing there could be.. but I'am not sure.)

Answers like yes/no would be nice :)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried getting those answers by writing test code and then debugging it? That's an easy way to get yes/no answers from the language and framework.

Comment: It's right, under conditions. I think that with negative numbers, >> doesn't give the same result as /. And you can use it with integers only, not with floats.

Comment: If you aren't sure what bit-shifting does, you are sure what dividing does, and you're thinking about one as a replacement for the other, why not save yourself, future you, and future maintainer of your code (perhaps you, perhaps not you) the trouble and just divide?

Comment: @Anthony true... and the compiler will optimize any performance differences away anyway.

Comment: See the link in the article referenced in the duplicate.  It describes when >> behaves like division, and when (more importantly) it doesn't...

Comment: My rule of thumb is use << and >> when you want to shift bits for bit manipulation, not when you want to perform an arithmetic trick, otherwise it becomes less maintainable.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare another difference in behavior between `>>` and `/`, not mentioned in the linked article, is precedence.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3060658/385844

Answer (score 1):

It does in fact do what you intend with int values, but you should be careful about edge cases such as negative numbers or very big numbers.

As for floating-point numbers, their memory representation is not that simple, so a simple shift-right won't do the trick of dividing by 2.

Comment: In fact, there is no `>>` operator on the floating point types.

Answer (score 1):

This is shift operator not divide , we know that shift left will multiply a number by 2 , For exmaple

2 in base 2 is : 0010 , if we shift it one times to left it will turn to 4 or 0100.

So as MSDN said :

If the first operand is an int or uint (32-bit quantity), the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of the second operand (second operand & 0x1f).

If the first operand is a long or ulong (64-bit quantity), the shift count is given by the low-order six bits of the second operand (second operand & 0x3f).

If the first operand is an int or long, the right-shift is an arithmetic shift (high-order empty bits are set to the sign bit). If the first operand is of type uint or ulong, the right-shift is a logical shift (high-order bits are zero-filled).

Comment: But the examples use the right-shift operator, which does indeed resemble division.